# Is it possible to correctly do math on numbers greater than 2^53?

Tags: javascript, numbers, limit

I am making a calculator in JavaScript that needs to be able to do precise math on numbers larger than `2^53`, which is `9007199254740992`. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "strint" library https://github.com/rauschma/strint.
For example:

```
    > var strint = require("./strint");
    > strint.add("9007199254740992", "1")
    '9007199254740993'
```